# Aws copy data from one S3 bucket to another on same account using lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to copy data from one S3 bucket to another in same account using lambda python. Can anyone help.

Comment: What have you done so far? Include any code snippets and attempts you've made

Comment: Does this answer your question? [boto3 - AWS lambda -copy files between buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434082/boto3-aws-lambda-copy-files-between-buckets)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object):

```py
response = client.copy_object(
    Bucket='string',
    Key='string',
    CopySource='string' or {'Bucket': 'string', 'Key': 'string', 'VersionId': 'string'},
    ...
)
```

Specify the destination in `Bucket` and `Key`, then specify the source in `CopySource`.

The easiest format for `CopySource` is: `source-bucket/folder/foo.txt`

Let us know if you are unfamiliar with writing Lambda functions or using boto3.